# React Native Webview Centering

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, webview

I'm using Webview in react native for rendering an embeded video
But the content can't centered even using flex alignitems and jusitfy content center
Is there any trick for centering a Webview content?
Or is there any way for rendering embed video without using Webview?

Code:

```
  <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
        width: width,
        height: height,
      }}>
      <WebView
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          width: width,
          height: height,
        }}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://movstar.xyz/embed/kPWOQDH3czGc7uR',
        }}
      />
   </View>
```

[Results of Webview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcXpt.png)

Comment: If you checkout the contents of https://movstar.xyz/embed/kPWOQDH3czGc7uR in the browser using chrome dev tools' mobile device simulator the web page itself is whats not centered vertically, you might try manually calculating the video size and setting your webview to that size, looks like the video has an aspect ratio of 1.77

Comment: Looks like you might want to use the inverse of that aspect ratio, 0.56. multiply the screen width by that ratio and it should give you a close enough height. Another option you might try is using that link as the source for a video element from react-native-video

Comment: I see, but how to use Embeded Video in react-native-video?, i think this library isn't support Embeded Video..., do you have any reference?